# Does Google AdWords care about duplicate content?

Tags: web-development, duplicate-content, google-ads

Our site offers several families of products, all of which have a common set of configurations.  For simplicity's sake, we'll say we offer products A, B and C, each with configurations 1, 2 and 3

- Products: A, B, C
- Configurations: 1, 2, 3

We want to create landing page <-> ad group combinations that reflect each possible combination of each product and configuration. Each product and each configuration have their own page, and so each landing page would have include the product content and the configuration content:

- ourproducts.com/A-1 (Contains copy for A and 1)
- ourproducts.com/A-2
- ourproducts.com/A-3
- ourproducts.com/B-1
- ... etc...

As you can see, this will lead to duplicate content across our product pages, though in different combinations.  My question is, does this matter from AdWords point of view?

Will there be any negative consequence to repeating portions of content this way?

Answer (score 1):

From Google's own [Understanding Landing Page Quality](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2404197) the only directly relevant comments I find on originality are

> What does your site offer that other sites don't?

and

> Try to offer useful features or content that are unique to your site.

as long as none of your content violates their [Advertising Policies](http://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1310864&guide=1308145&page=guide.cs) I see nothing that would negatively effect your rating.

Also once you put up the pages you can apparently use a Google tool for **Viewing your landing page quality**.

Answer (score 1):

If the content is exactly the same, but, for example, same products in different orders, Google will recognize it as a different page altogether, and not duplicate content.
It'll only be considerate duplicate if it is in case an exact copy.